# Populate Individual Email Result On Contacts\leads

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-field

I want to auto populate the "Hard Bounce" field present in the individual email result on its related contact or lead . For Example if it checked on any of the individual email result in Salesforce , it should be checked on the related contact or lead.

How can I achieve this (the "Hard Bounce" field is a custom field which will be made by us) ?

Comment: Dave,
I am interested in if you have found a solution. I am also interested in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Hard bounce is stored in salesforce's master operational data extensions and it's not editable. Are you looking for a way to display a contact's hard bounce count essentially outside of their subscriber view?

If you want to create your own DE that looks up bounces corresponding to your subscriber ID you could, and then populate your contact with that data. Is that what you're after? What's your use case?